# Where to find Google Chrome logs

Tags: google-chrome, logging

Where to find the Google Chrome logs? In which location can I find the Chrome logs if it crashes?

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Comment: please be more specific in your question. what you are trying to?

Comment: @Gapchoos :I have developed a web application which runs on the chrome browser. However, when the application has to process and display loads of data the Google chrome browser crashes. In order to track what is causing the crash I need the logs as they are the best sources of information for bug finding.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Jordan Meyer: Windows 8

Answer (score 15):

First, you must enable crash logging in advanced settings by ticking "Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google".
Crash logs can then be found in `chrome://crashes`.
Note that by enabling this, your crash reports and stats will be sent to Google servers...

Comment: Great if you can get into Chrome, not so great if you cannot open Chrome because it crashes.

Answer (score 6):

Dump files are stored under %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Crashpad\reports

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/624/where-is-google-chrome-crash-dump-located

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS 10.13.4
Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I got:

~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Crashpad/completed/

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, if you cannot access the Chrome settings page, create a shortcut for chrome and add the following flag to the target.

```
--enable-logging --v=1
```

Then run Chrome using that shortcut, and you can see the log file in your user folder.

```
C:\Users\[User name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\chrome_debug.log
```

[Chrome Browser debug logs](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwindows)

[image]