# Google Chrome has insufficient permissions to download a file from my script

Tags: google-chrome

I have a csv download script but it is returning an error below when overwriting a file.

> Failed - Insufficient permissions - google chrome

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="import_registrations.csv"');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ($data as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the permission for the default downloads directory of chrome was changed.

try this.

```
$chmod -R 776 <downloads-directory>
```

ex:

```
$chmod -R 776 ~/Downloads
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out to be a virus checker intervening between Chrome and the hard disk, and preventing the disk write because it was suspicious of the file (false positive, as it turned out).

Answer (score 0):

Run Chrome from the command-line with [enabled logging](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging):

```
chromium --enable-logging=stderr --v=1
```

<sup>Check also: [Where to find Google Chrome logs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12740440/55075)</sup>

then reproduce the issue.

For macOS, check: [How to filter logs via processImagePath?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304219/22781)

The output will be saved to the file `chrome_debug.log` in [Chrome's user data directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md).

Suggestions:

- Make sure your Downloads folder has proper permissions.
- Your [user data folder](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) has proper permissions as well.

  - For Windows, check: [Where are the user profile directories of Google Chrome located in?](https://superuser.com/q/329112/87805)
  - For Ubuntu Linux, from Snap store, check `~/snap/chromium` folder
- On Ubuntu, check `kern.log` messages via `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`.
- Check any custom modifications to `chrome://flags/` (consider resetting to default).
- Check for any crashes at `chrome://crashes/`.
- Related bug report: [Issue 942514: kernel audit: type=1400 audit: apparmor="DENIED"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=942514).
- Check [Tips for debugging on Linux](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/docs/linux_debugging.md) and [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension).